# Galois Representations and Eigenvalues

Tags: representation-theory, galois-representations

Suppose you have two ($\ell$-adic) Galois representations $V$ and $W$ and you know that each Frobenius-eigenvalue (at unramified primes) for $V$ is also one for $W$.

Is this enough to obtain a Galois-equivariant map between $V$ and $W$? Or does this only serve as a hope that there could be such a map?

Comment: This has come up before here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3175473/the-splitting-of-galois-representations?rq=1

Comment: Oh, thanks for pointing this out! Mhhh... but it is a necessary condition (for either an embedding or a Gal-projection to exist), right?